# Topological space example

Tags: general-topology

What would be an example of topological space having any two points say $x_1, x_2$, such that each open set containing one point ( $x_1$) also contains the other point $x_2$

Comment: You could take the trivial topology on $\{ x_1, x_2 \}$

Answer (score 2):

Look at the trivial topology $\{ \emptyset, X \}$ for any set $X$ that has at least two members.

Comment: @David The only open sets of this topology are $\emptyset$ and $X$. Hence, if an open set contains any point of the space, it contains all its points. In particular, if $x_1, x_2$ are distinct elements of $X$ and $O$ is open in the given topology, then $x_1 \in O \implies O = X$ and hence also implies $x_2 \in O$.

Answer (score 0):

The property you describe is related to the Hausdorff property.

> **Definition:** A topological space $X$ is Hausdorff if for any $x,y\in x$ with $x\neq y$ there are open neighbourhoods $U_x$, $U_y$ of $x$ resp $y$ such that $U_x \cap U_y = \emptyset$

So every space fulfilling your conditions hast to be non-Hausdorff.

There are many examples of non-Hausdorff spaces, but they are all a bit unintuitive as we can't separate points by open sets.
Famous examples are the trivial topology or the Zarisky topology.

You can check if these topologies fulfil your requirements.

Comment: There is a weaker property than Hausdorff called $T_1$, which is more strongly related. Specifically the Zariski topology on an algebraic variety is $T_1$, and so cannot satisfy the requirements.